# Should question about Intel Compute Stick be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

[Intel Compute Stick](http://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/compute-stick/intel-compute-stick.html) is a compute-on-a-stick device.

For example it can be used to connect to your TV via HDMI (making it part of IoT?).

Would question about it be on-topic? If it depends, then on what?

Answer (score 4):

Questions about general purposes devices are on topic *only* when the question is specific to using them for an IoT purpose; questions about IoT specific products are on topic unless the question really has nothing to do with IoT.

Just like any computer from a PC to a PDP-8 to an Arduino, a question **specific to using this computing device for an IoT purpose** would be on topic, while a question about just trying to use it in general would not be.

**Driving a TV via an HDMI port is not an Internet of Things topic** - it's just hooking a computer up to a display, which ever since the deprecation of the printing terminal has been the usual way people use computers.  Or if you mean you want to watch movies on it, then it is just a home entertainment topic, and not Internet of Things either.

Now, if you want to hook it up to your coffee maker, some might ask *why* but at least that would be an IoT topic.