# Can I ask questions about smart TV not connecting / working properly here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I've an issue with a particular piece of software that came with the tv not being able to connect in a smart TV. Would that type of question be on-topic as part of the IoT exchange.

My thoughts are it could be because a TV is one of things in the internet of things.

If not on-topic here are there other sites that it would be on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

**Probably not**, unless the undescribed piece of software accomplishes a clearly IoT purpose.

**Content Delivery** aspects of a "smart TV" are not really IoT topics - they're simply "yet another way to sell you media", and indeed, that is quite consistent with the previous question about using a "compute stick" to drive a TV.

However, using a "smart TV" to interface to a home control system could well be on topic - the topic worthiness coming from the control of gadgets in the home, not from the "smart TV".

Using a "smart TV" to monitor a security video camera is a bit borderline - if it's just closed circuit TV, conceptually just taking what's been available for years (even picture-in-picture is old technology) and piping it over an IP network rather than coax, that doesn't seem very worthy.  But add in multiple types of sensors and custom configurable threshold rules, and it might start to be.

**For a simple guideline**, remember that a "smart TV" is just a computer with a large screen designed to be operated with a handheld remote in the living room.  If a particular application wouldn't be an IoT topic if done on a desktop computer (for example, watching youtube videos) then it isn't an IoT topic if done on a "smart TV", either.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally say, **absolutely yes.**  It's part of the Internet of Things, which is the basic subject of this stack.  It has to do with being able to connect a smart application, which is the also basically the topic of this site.

That being said, do check out [How to ask](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center, and make sure your question will not be too broad or primarily opinion based.  Check out the [help center](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help), and...

### Welcome aboard!

Comment: What about this answer https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/should-question-about-intel-compute-stick-be-on-topic it sort of says don't unless its particularly interesting.

Comment: A "smart TV" is just a funny shaped personal computer.  It's going to take more than that to make something an IoT topic.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, if the question is just about how to use your Smart TV, I concur.  However, I was reading the question to be about *connecting* the smart TV.  Would that not be about remotely controlling the environment?

Comment: If it's connecting it to a device to be controlled or monitored then yes.  But if it's just to connect the smart TV to the Internet *in general* or for its core marketed purposes of streaming media, then no.